# What tag is prepended to the question title to make the bookmark text?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Look at the question [How do we maintain answer quality when everybody thinks they're experts?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/how-do-we-maintain-answer-quality-when-everybody-thinks-theyre-experts).

If I hit Ctrl-D in FireFox this is what it proposes as link text:

> content curation - How do we maintain answer quality when everybody thinks they're experts? - Community Building Stack Exchange

It's obvious that the (first) **content-curation** tag is prepended to the link text (sanitized to remove the hyphen).

Now look at [Advantages to storing content locally vs outsourcing it to a 3rd party](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/667/advantages-to-storing-content-locally-vs-outsourcing-it-to-a-3rd-party).
If I again hit Ctrl-D, this is the proposed link text:

> small communities - Advantages to storing content locally vs outsourcing it to a 3rd party - Community Building Stack Exchange

The text of the **second** tag is prepended.

If you look at the [edit history of the first question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/1113/revisions) you see that the tags were never edited. The second question currently has no edit history.

**Question: what determines which tag text gets prepended to the proposed hyperlink text?**

I have searched [here](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+bookmark+tag) and on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+bookmark+tag) thinking that this question actually belongs over there, but with no results. Actually, this prepending of tags does not happen across SE sites (tested on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and on meta.SE itself) - for all I know it could be specific to Community Building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first or second tag, sorted by popularity, that is not in the title is prepended to the title.

In your examples:

- [How do we maintain answer quality when everybody thinks they're experts?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/how-do-we-maintain-answer-quality-when-everybody-thinks-theyre-experts) The top tag of the two on the question is [content-curation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-curation) with 19 questions (versus [community-standard](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-standard) with 7), so it is added to the title
- [Advantages to storing content locally vs outsourcing it to a 3rd party](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/667/advantages-to-storing-content-locally-vs-outsourcing-it-to-a-3rd-party) [small-communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-communities) barely wins on this question with 20 questions, so it is added to the title.

Comment: I never could've guessed that ;-) Now, *is* this specific to CB?

Comment: @Jan, no it is network wide

Comment: Oh, no *wonder* I'd never worked it out on my own!  I've wondered about this for years but never enough to actually ask the question.

Comment: Yep! [Source for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180384/).